# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030, when saving data

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode6

With an iOS app that has been working for about a year; I am thinking of an update. For that I recompiled it in the last version of Xcode (6.3.2).
Then, when trying to insert a record in Core Data, I got this message in the debugging console:

> Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 "The operation
>   couldn't be completed. (Cocoa error 134030.) "

After looking for a solution on the net and finding nothing, and also making a few test with no conclusion. I decided to write this post.

Has any one had similar experience and found what was wrong?

Comment: There must be more to the error than just an error code. It will be hard to help you without seeing it. Also, can you give any kind of context around where and when the error occurs? Any code samples?

Comment: Actually, I think there was not much more, that is why it took me time to solve. Anyway, I found the problem: my store was not properly opened for read-write, it was only read-only. After I fixed this, everything started to work. Thank you in any case.